# По клику на кнопку "Добавить в корзину" конкретного товара, нужно вывести ему же галочку с помощью js

Tags: javascript, java

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как по клику на кнопку "Добавить в корзину" конкретного товара - вывести ему же галочку, что товар успешно добавлен?
Вот пример - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/8kvj0oL9/2/)
Пробовал через `data-show="0"` сравнивать - не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое что вы должны понимать, нужно ли вам добавлять ещё несколько товаров или возможно только 1 раз, если нужно добавить несколько, то ставить птичку нет ни какого смысла, пользователь может просто не понять, можно ли добавить еще товар или уже нельзя так как есть птичка. Наверно нужно ему показывать на время данную птичку а потом скрывать.Если же у вас возможно добавить только один товар, то тогда надо связывать все с сервером, то есть отправлять на сервер что товар добавлен и блокировать добавление в корзину + ставить в data-show цифру 1, что на мой взгляд не правильно. Но вот что вы хотели если по существу.

```js
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
    var that = $(this),
        shows = parseInt(that.attr("data-show"),10),
        add = that.attr("data-text");
    if(shows == 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        that.attr("data-show", "1");
        that.text(add);
      that.closest('.catalog-tovarov').find('#mot').show();
     }
});
```

```css
.catalog-tovarov{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;margin:0 0 20px 11px;width:150px;height:200px;padding: 1%;transition:0.4s 0.2s ease;background:#cfcfcf;}
.catalog-tovarov:hover{box-shadow: 0 4px 9px 0 #CECECE;}
.price{margin-top:120px;}
#mot{display: none; text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog-tovarov">
    <div id="mot"><img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" /></div>
     <div class="price">
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="catalog-tovarov">
     <div id="mot">
        <img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" />
    </div>
     <div class="price">
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="catalog-tovarov">
    <div id="mot">
        <img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!  С помощью PHP всё проверяется, то есть после обновления страницы, галочка останется и будет также вместо кнопки "Добавить в корзину" - "Перейти в корзину", а также в data-show можно уже записать цифру 1.  Примерно так:   `data-show="<?php if($_SESSION['cart'][$product['goods_id']]['qty'] > 0): ?>1<?php else:?>0<?php endif; ?>"`  Или же думал показывать плавно галочку на время и плавно на время вместо надписи "Добавить в корзину" - просто показать галочку в кнопке вместо текста или же написать текст - "Добавлен". Но, как это реализовать, пока не знаю)

Comment: Поправил код, по клику теперь проверяется если стоит 0 то менять текст на перейти в корзину, только путь у ссылки поставьте на корзину, если добавлено то ссылка будит работать как обычный переход

Comment: Очень благодарен Вам! Спасибо:) Но только вот `e.preventDefault();` в условии этом писать не желательно, т.к. у меня с карточки товара, товар добавляется сколько угодно раз, да и любопытные могут поменять через панель разработчика значение в data-show:) Поэтому `e.preventDefault();`  будет стоять не в условии, а в самом начале, как в примере было у меня. В таком случае можно ли как-то удалить class, а именно add-to-cart у ссылки, также, как добавляется ссылка или текст? При том, что есть дополнительно еще один класс для стилизации кнопочки.

Comment: $(this).removeClass('add-to-cart'); не совсем понял только зачем это, те кто любопытный может сделать много чего)))

Comment: то есть вы хотите просто убирать класс add-to-cart чтоб ссылка работала как обычно, ну в принципе можно и так

Comment: Class удаляется отлично, но почему-то ссылка также работает, как `e.preventDefault();`, а по идее должен отключаться дефолт и переводить уже на корзину. Ссылку я заменяю, всё хорошо.  А необходимо для того, чтобы с карточки товара, товар можно было добавлять сколько угодно раз по клику на "Добавить в корзину". Там нет необходимости заменять ссылку и текст. Поэтому если так все оставить, в карточке товара код будет работать точно также как в каталоге товаров. Надеюсь поняли) А от любителей я стараюсь прописывать проверочки)

Comment: да, надо делегировать клик, тоесть перепишите первую строку на вот такую $(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart', function (e) { тогда e.preventDefault() не будит запоминаться после первого клика

Comment: Вас понял. Спасибо огромное! Всё работает отлично:)

Comment: `that = $(this),
shows = parseInt(that.attr("data-show"),10),
add = that.attr("data-text");     
  if(shows==0){
              that.closest('.product-table').find('#mot3').show('slow');
                 $(this).removeClass('add-to-cart');
                 that.attr("data-show", "1");               
                 that.text(add);
                 that.attr("href", "http://korzinaajax.loc/order_login");              
             }`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Прошу прощения снова за беспокойство. Заметил следующее, при добавлении товара с карточки товара, ссылке прописывается также data-show="1", а также удаляет class и меняет ссылку. Причем первые 2 раза кликается на кнопку еще нормально (идет добавление товара в корзину), но на 3 раз клика уже удаляется класс, меняется ссылка и добавляется data-show="1" и ссылка переводит получается также в корзину, как с каталога товаров. Как это можно исправить? Код выше в комментарии.

Comment: Данный вопрос закрыт, открывайте новый и там пишите код нормально, ни чего не понял.

Comment: Готово - [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625572/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0)