# Не изменять ссылку в карточке товара при добавлении в корзину товара

Tags: javascript, java

Здравствуйте!

Имеется кусочек кода, который с каталога товаров при клике на кнопку "Добавить в корзину" конкретного товара - добавляет галочку этому товару, меняет текст на "Перейти в корзину", также соответственно меняет путь ссылки (переход в корзину), изменяет значение у ссылки `data-show` с 0 на цифру 1 и удаляет `class="add-to-cart"` у ссылки, чтобы не сработало `e.preventDefault();`

Проблема в том, что это же самое срабатывает и с карточки товара на 3-й клик по кнопке "Добавить в корзину" (1-й и 2-й клик работает нормально - идёт добавление товара в корзину). В карточке товара нет необходимости изменять путь ссылки, добавлять ссылке `data-show="1"` и удалять `class="add-to-cart"` у ссылки, чтобы не сработало `e.preventDefault();`

Код JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     that = $(this),
        shows = parseInt(that.attr("data-show"),10),
        add = that.attr("data-text");      
        if(shows==0){
           that.closest('.catalog-tovarov').find('#mot3').show('slow');
           $(this).removeClass('add-to-cart');
           that.attr("data-show", "1");                  
           that.text(add);
           that.attr("href", "http://test.ru/korzina");              
        }
});
```

Код с каталога товаров:

```
<div class="catalog-tovarov">
   <div id="mot3" style="display: none;">
      <img src="images/check.png" />
   </div>
   <a class="add-to-cart" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="http://test.ru/addtocart/6">Добавить в корзину</a>
</div>
```

Код с карточки товара:

```
<div class="product-kartochka">
   <a class="add-to-cart" href="http://test.ru/addtocart/6">Добавить в корзину</a>
</div>
```

Суть в том, что надо скорее всего как-то конкретно обратиться к ссылке только в каталоге товаров (возможно по id), а для ссылки в карточке товара изменять ни чего не надо.
Надеюсь на Вашу помощь:)

Comment: При событии на клик изменить на  ".catalog-tovarov > .add-to-cart" не пробовали

Comment: @Олександр Он и так там содержится и без клика. Наоборот, после клика с каталога товаров удаляет этот класс, что и нужно, а с карточки товара этого делать не нужно. Либо я вас не правильно понял или вы наоборот.

Comment: Что-то я не понял. Вы хотите, чтобы это событие не срабатывало при клики с карточки товара, верно? Но в ней у вас стоит такой же класс как и в каталоге, а я вам предлагаю обращаться к add-to-cart, который находиться в catalog-tovarov, то-есть при клике в карточке товаров оно такого класса находить не будет, а с-венно и не будет удалять. Или в чем проблема?

Comment: @Олександр Да верно. Нужно только чтобы это все сработало для каталога товаров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В else делаете все нужные манипуляции для кнопки которая находится в карточке товара

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 that = $(this),
    shows = parseInt(that.attr("data-show"),10),
    parent = that.closest('.catalog-tovarov'),
    add = that.attr("data-text");   

    if(shows==0  && parent.hasClass('catalog-tovarov')){
       parent.find('#mot3').show('slow');
       $(this).removeClass('add-to-cart');
       that.attr("data-show", "1");                  
       that.text(add);
       that.attr("href", "http://test.ru/korzina");              
    }
    else{

    }});
```

Comment: Отлично! Все работает, спасибо! Пойду дальше изучать JS. Посоветуйте хорошие источники, где можно изучить язык js:)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/loftblog/playlists?shelf_id=0&sort=dd&view=1 канал с видео уроками где много видео по разным тематикам для разработки сайтов, и не только

Comment: Благодарю! И спасибо за Вашу помощь:)

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим мой комментаррий, если это то что вам нужно то вот пробуем этот вариант

```
$(document).on('click', '.catalog-tovarov>.add-to-cart', function (e) {
 console.log(1);
});
```

и смотрим в консоль. То что вам нужно?

Comment: Спасибо, но так не будет работать добавление товара с карточки товара, так как в вашем случает это будет работать только с каталога товаров. Посмотрите ответ ниже.